# Counting values in a range only if a condition outside the range is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a table of data and want to count how many times a string shows in a range, so I'm doing `=COUNTIF(C2:R100,"APPLE")` and that counts how many times "APPLE" shows up in the range `C2` through `R100`. That works great.

However, I have another column X that has percentages for each row and I want to only count "APPLE" if the percentage for that row is above 50%. I tried doing `=COUNTIFS(C2:R100,"APPLE",X2:X100,">0.5")` but get an error that the ranges are not the same. I also tried `=SUMPRODUCT(C2:R100="APPLE",X2:X100=">0.5")` and get an error that the ranges have mismatched range sizes.

Is there a way to do this in a single formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an old-fashioned [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) alternative.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:R100="APPLE")*(X2:X100>0.5))
```

You were almost there. SUMPRODUCT uses more directly mathematical formulation than a [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) or [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) function.

[image: sump_countifs]

Comment: and what is the result of this old-fashioned multiplying ranges of different shape please? `C2*X2 + D2*X2 + ...` or `C2*X2 + D2*#REF! + ...`?

Comment: So =SUMPRODUCT((C2:R100="APPLE")*(X2:X100>0.5)) *seems* to work but I'm getting funky numbers. For example, it says it counts 1 result for rows over 57%, but  57% is the highest percentage value. It also counts 11 results over 50% but there are actually 14 in that range.

Comment: @Keith - Cannot explain your aberrant results. Could you possibly have text values that look like numbers mixed in with actual numbers?

Comment: @Keith are you sure the 3 extra results are > 50% and not equal to 50%? and there are no spaces around the "apple" value?